# incorrect highcharts export server js script error codes

Tags: highcharts

When invoking the the highcharts-convert.js as mentioned [here](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/52-serverside-generated-charts), I noticed that it is returning success code 0 even if the input json is invalid.  For example:

```
karl$ phantomjs ./app/javascript/highcharts-convert.js -infile ./spec/fixtures/invalid_input.json -outfile /var/folders/q2/m5hn1wq54zg33s7jv31d1p280000gq/T/hello.82829.54862.png -width 300
SyntaxError: Parse error

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: options

  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():57
    phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():99
      phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():99
      loading images...
      loading images...
      loading images...
      loading images...
      loading images...
      loading images...
      loading images...
      loading images...
      loading images...
      loading images...
      loading images...
      loading images...
      loading images...
      loading images...
      loading images...
      loading images...
      loading images...
      loading images...
      loading images...
      loading images...
      loading images...
      loading images...
      loading images...
      loading images...
      loading images...
      loading images...
      loading images...
      loading images...
      loading images...
      karl$ echo $?
      0
```

Without a proper error code, it seems to me that there is no way for my job to know that the command failed.  Am i missing something?

thx.

-karl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the method page.evaluate() the script tries to set the option variable, see [highcharts-convert.jsline#166](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/blob/master/exporting-server/phantomjs/highcharts-convert.js#L166). Most likely your Json file isn't properly read from the filesystem. Try to set in a console.log() statement here  [highcharts-convert.jsL#148](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/blob/master/exporting-server/phantomjs/highcharts-convert.js#L148) to verify the file has been read.

You're right, that a error message should be provided at this point.

**UPDATE**
It seems the error is thrown while having a syntax error in the inputfile. This is detected during PhantomsJS page.evaluate() function. For security reasons is this execution sandboxed.

The only way (to my knowledge) to get something out of this sandbox is using console.log() and setting a callback function for page.onConsoleMessage.

You could do something like this:

```
HC.optionsParsed = 'Highcharts.options.parsed';

window.optionsParsed = false;

page.onConsoleMessage = function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
    /*
    * Ugly hacks, but only way to get messages out of the 'page.evaluate()'
    * sandbox. If any, please contribute with improvements on this!
    */
    if (msg === HC.optionsParsed) {
        window.optionsParsed = true;
    }
};

// later on in page evaluate
svg = page.evaluate(function (width, constr, optionsStr, callbackStr, pdfOutput) {
    var imagesLoadedMsg = 'Highcharts.images.loaded', $container, chart,
                nodes, nodeIter, elem, opacity;

    // dynamic script insertion
    function loadScript(varStr, codeStr) {
        var $script = $('<script>').attr('type', 'text/javascript');
        $script.html('var ' + varStr + ' = ' + codeStr);
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild($script[0]);

        // HERE IT HAPPENS, run console.log with a specific message to set window.Optionsparsed to true
        if (window[varStr] !== undefined) {
            console.log('Highcharts.' + varStr + '.parsed');
        }
 }
// ... SCRIPT CONTINUES ...
```

when the page.evaluate method ends. We can check if the window.optionsParsed is set to true. And if not raise a warning and exit.

```
if (!window.optionsParsed) {
    console.log('ERROR - the options variable was not available, contains the infile an syntax error? see' + input);
    phantom.exit();
}
```

I also updated the the [highcharts-convert.js](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/blob/master/exporting-server/phantomjs/highcharts-convert.js) script on Github.

Comment: Well there is an error message there is not error code returned from the phantomjs script which means that the caller of phantomjs does not really know if the process finished succesfully or not without parsing the stdout/stderr.  Looking at the script, i think the problem is with the way the javascript object is loaded by dynamically adding a script tag  https://gist.github.com/4691047.  When this script is added there is no error raised to phantomjs if the script is invalid.  Wondering if there is a better way to do this?  Thx!

Comment: Gotcha.. so basically use onConsoleMessage to communicate outside of the sandbox.  This is pretty limiting.. I am no expert in phantomjs but it seems like there should be a better way to do this.  I feel like the main issue is that the input file is added to the page by inserting a script tag into the head via jquery.  Would it be possible to do this instead with an evaluate function?  Then we can just call phantom.exit(1) if the evaluate function fails.  I know i am probably oversimplifying this...

Comment: It's limiting, true. But it works. In the meantime we have to wait if PhantomJS comes up with a better solution, I guess. The main issue is that syntax / parse errors only occur during the sandboxed execution in page.evaluate().

Answer (score 0):

I was Stuck with the similar issue 100% same issue please check your highstock.js file type if it is binary file please follow the following steps and your problem get solved

curl http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js -o exporting-server/phantomjs/highstock.js.gz

gzip -d exporting-server/phantomjs/highstock.js.gz